# Wix component conditions don't work as expected

Tags: wix, components, conditional-statements

I've seen other posts describing component conditions not being evaled based on feature state, but my question is much simpler.

Given the following:

```
<Property Id="WORDISINSTALLED" Secure="yes">
    <RegistrySearch Id="FindWordIsInstalled" Root="HKCR" Key="Word.Application" Type="raw"  Win64="$(var.Win64)"/>
</Property>

<Property Id="WORDVERSION" Secure="yes">
    <RegistrySearch Id="WordVersion" Root="HKCR" Key="Word.Application\CurVer" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="MIN_WORD_VERSION_INSTALLED" After ="AppSearch" Value="1">
    <![CDATA[WORDVERSION <> "Word.Application.11" AND WORDVERSION <> "Word.Application.12" AND WORDISINSTALLED]]>
</SetProperty>
```

I should be able to do this:

```
<Component Id="$(var.SOFFWordAddinReg_Id)" DiskId="1" Guid="$(var.SOFFWordAddinReg_Guid)" Win64="$(var.Win64)">
    <Condition>MIN_WORD_VERSION_INSTALLED</Condition>
      <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns" Name="Description" Value="yada" Type="string" Action="write"/>
    </Component>
```

With the expectation that component var.SOFFWordAddinReg_Id will only be installed if MIN_WORD_VERSION_INSTALLED is non-null and TRUE.

I see from the logs that WORDISINSTALLED is set to "Microsoft Word Application" and WORDVERSION is set to "Word.Application.14" (in AppSearch), but MIN_WORD_VERSION_INSTALLED is not set:

Skipping action:  SetMIN_WORD_VERSION_INSTALLED.FA651678_2CA2_423F_9FE0_FE10237B33F6 (condition is false)

The logs also show the component 
Component: SOFFWordAddinReg.7D199B30_06E3_488C_9EDF_4B8188026E9C; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Null;   Client State: Unknown

but don't say why. (I assume because of the condition?)

I must be doing something *very basic* wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean expressions should use parens, as the precedence of Boolean operators is <= comparison operators,e.g. should be:

```
<![CDATA[(WORDVERSION <> "Word.Application.11") AND (WORDVERSION <> "Word.Application.12") AND (WORDISINSTALLED)]]>
```